# Prefill html form with element without ID

Tags: html, forms

I have a form:

```html
<form action="#" method="post" class="aui" id="advanced-settings-form">
    <input class="text medium-long-field" type="text" name="6" placeholder="/**/*">
</form>
```

I know that it is possible to prefill the form via url as: `URL?id=text`

But in my case there is no id - only a name.

Is it still possible to prefill the form via URL?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for sending data through a form, we use `name` attribute and not `id` attribute. What you are looking for is to use `value` attribute of `<input>` tag.

Also `URL?id=text` which you have mentioned, means that the form has already been submitted using`method=get`. It has no relation with prefilling of the input boxes.

Something like this:-

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="aui" id="advanced-settings-form">
    <input class="text medium-long-field" type="text" name="name_here" placeholder="/**/*" value="text">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't need to send - I need to prefill via URL.

Comment: Yes I know. If you use `value` attribute, the input field would be prefilled with the attribute's value. If you are still not understanding my point, use the above code first and then read the comment.

Comment: You don't understand my point - I can't change HTML. I can only use URL.

Comment: Okay now I got it. You actually need `name` for filling and sending data through forms. Just read this : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp#:~:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,passed%20when%20submitting%20a%20form and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: What I mean is `URL?id=text` is incorrect and `URL? name=text` is correct.

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".") Source :https://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/95687-use-within-id-name-attribute-input-tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227472/discussion-between-user12137152-and-michael).